# Retail decimal rounding conditions using custom rounding rules

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, rounding

In MS excel I am trying to create a retail price according to these conditions:

If retail price ends between .11 and .36, retail price will end in .31  ex: $5.15 = $5.31

If retail price ends between .95 and .00, retail price will end in .96  ex: $5.00 = $4.96 and $5.98 = $5.96

How can I apply these conditions in Excel to a set of retail prices, looking at the decimal places and having an output defined by custom/random conditions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula to achieve the same:

```
=IF(AND(MOD(C3,1)>=0.11,MOD(C3,1)<=0.36),0.31+INT(C3),IF(AND(MOD(C3,1)>=0.95,MOD(C3,1)<=0.99),0.96+INT(C3),IF(MOD(C3,1)=0,INT(C3)-1+0.96,MOD(C3,1)+INT(C3))))
```

Where, **C3** contains your retail price.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather create a table with the references for maintainability and customizability like below:

[image]

And enter in the other ranges that don't fall anywhere as well, with `=NA()` as their rounding result to indicate that the number shouldn't be changed.

The formula I used in B2 is:

```
=IFERROR(INT(A2)+SUMIFS(F:F,D:D,"<="&IF(MOD(A2,1)=0,1,MOD(A2,1)),E:E,">="&IF(MOD(A2,1)=0,1,MOD(A2,1))),A2)
```